# How to load an codeigniter application by using different url

Tags: codeigniter, saas

Now I am developing an application by using `CodeIgniter framework`.  In this application, there is a section which name account setup. By using this section we can create multiple accounts. As an example, accounts name are abc,  bca or anything. And Suppose my site URL is: `www.xyz.com (base_url)` Then we need to access the site by the domain name and also domain name with account name like bellow:

> www.xyz.com
>
> www.xyz.com/abc/
>
> www.xyz.com/bca/
>
> www.xyz.com/anything/

For More clear, URL pattern will be:

> www.xyz.com/dashboard/index
>
> www.xyz.com/abc/dashboard/index
>
> www.xyz.com/bca/dashboard/index

How can we do it? I need your suggestion.

Comment: You mean when you hit the url like this `www.xyz.com/newproject` it will open your new project which is located on other domain like this `www.mxy.com` am i right Ashish.

Comment: @yaseen-ahmad, actually by using same script, from the same domain, I want to run  the project by different url (www.xyz.com/newproject or www.xyz.com/newproject1 or www.xyz.com) .

Comment: yes it's possible see my answer hope it's will help you @Ashish

Comment: @yaseen-ahmed, I need more suggestion. Let me describe more, I am creating an application. In this application, there is a section which name account setup. By using this section we can create multiple accounts.   Suppose, accounts name are abc, bca or anything. Suppose my site url is: www.xyz.com (base_url)
Then we need to access the site like : 
www.xyz.com/abc/, (base_url)
www.xyz.com/bca/, (base_url)

For More clear, url pattern will be : 
www.xyz.com/dashboard/index
www.xyz.com/abc/dashboard/index
www.xyz.com/bca/dashboard/index

Comment: I think you trying to do this, for example I have 2 accounts 1 AB 2 CA, you mean when user login the urls look like this www.xyz.com/AB and www.xyz.com/CA am i right. if yes see my answer 2nd example it's possible.

Comment: @yaseen-ahmed, befor login, also I need same url pattern. for AB, for registration user, url will be like www.xyz.com/ab/registration, so when a user will register by using this url then this user registration will be under AB account .  Already In my project I have set base_url www.xyz.com/ in confiq file. So when I am browsing www.xyz.com/ab, then I am getting error: This page is not define. Thanks

Comment: oh my God i don't know how to explain this to you see for registration you well use a url like this `www.xyz.com/registration` when user registrar in system then you well get his info from data base and then you will redirect him like this `redirect("".$user_name."/dashboard/index"` if you can do this let me know i will fix this for you

Comment: hahahah it's some kind of challenge for me

Comment: @YaseenAhmed, It is working finely. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it's Possible through codeigniter Routs.
Go to `application\config` Open a file which Name is routes.php
you can call the controller functions see in code example

**example**

```
$route['new_project'] = "controller/function";
```

when you hit your website url like this `www.xyz.com/new_project` it will go to your mention controller and function.

see the documentation of routs [CodeIgniter  URI Routing](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/routing.html)

**example 2:**

```
$route['account/(.*)']    = "controller/function";
```

Now we you redirect your url like this

```
redirect('account/'.$name_var.'');
```

Now your url look like this.

```
www.xyz.com/account/name_of_logged_in_user
```

Also you can use this like this.

```
$route['(.*)/dashboard/index']    = "controller/function";
```

And then you can call it like this.

```
redirect(''.$name_var.'/dashboard/index');
```

And from this code your output url show something like this.

```
www.xyz.com/name_of_logged_in_user/dashboard/index
```

Hope it will help you if any question add comment

Answer (score 0):

There are many way to do it.

1) Domain alias if you want to run same script with different domain.

2) if you want to run same script with sub domain then you can do it from Cpanel

3) If you want to run same script with different folders in same domain then you need to use htaccess